# VS2012 build fails when setting CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors although there are no warnings or errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build, code-analysis

I'm struggling with the following situation:

There is a bunch of projects (14 to be precise) in a VS2012 solution.
These projects are free from Code Analysis warnings and errors.

I would like to use the CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors switch for our build server, so the build fails in case there are any CA issues. This is accomplished by setting the environment variable "CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors" to "true". This flag is consumed by Code Analysis as parameter (see C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets).

When building the solution from FinalBuilder (on the build server or on my machine) or from command line (through devenv.com), VS2012 output tells me that there are no Code Analysis warnings and no errors at all - but the build fails with no further reason.

I isolated the problem to the following pieces:

- it is one single project that causes the fail. If i delete its binaries, the error can always be reproduced (this project uses the exact same .targets files and other environment stuff as the other projects)
- if I set CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors to false, the build succeeds (again, with 0 warnings and 0 errors).

The output from VS2012 is pretty poor and (according to my researches) there is no way to increase the verbosity level for devenv.com.

It looks like this:

```
1>------ Skipped Build: Project: xxxxxx_Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>------ Build started: Project: xxxx.xxxx.Modules.Base, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>  xxxx.xxxx.Modules.Base -> X:\xxx\x64\Debug\xxxx.xxxx.Modules.Base.dll
2>  Running Code Analysis...
2>  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 12 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

FinalBuilder adds the return value:

```
devenv.com returned Error code : 1
```

Does anybody have any ideas what could cause the build to fail only when setting CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors to *true* although there are no warnings and errors at all?

Comment: You can increase VS' verbosity. Go to `Tools,Options,Projects And Solutions, Build And Run`, and take a look at the last two combo boxes.

Comment: Thats only for MSBuild; devenv's verbosity (command line: `devenv.com /build "Debug|x64" "....project.sln"`) cannot be altered. Unfortunately, running the build with CA _inside_ VS2012 succeeds every time.

Comment: Why not use MSBuild then?

Comment: MSBuild has other flaws, e.g. builds differ when building from within VS2012 and through MSBuild, resulting in constand "rebuilds". And there was a problem with multi-core-compilation as well if I remember right.
**However** your idea is good, I could use MSBuild for further investigations in that problem. And indeed, I can reproduce the error with "diagnostic output". Now digging through thousands of lines...

Comment: found it - by reading really lots of verbose output...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem:

That line of MSBuild-output made me curious and finally led to the right place:

`The indirectly-referenced assembly '...dll' could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by: ...dll`

Indeed, there was an assembly of third-party software that did not match the referenced version.

Obviously, that did not produce any error or warning at all, but, when activating `CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors`, Code Analysis thought it's better to return with an error.

So, the solution was to (temporarily) use MSBuild with different verbosity-levels ('diagnostic' was too much, 'detailed' gave me still about 29.800 lines for code analysis of that single assembly-project, including the missing assembly name), digging through that stuff and finding the needle in the haystack...

Thanks to **dario_ramos** for pointing me towards the right direction!